# Wordpress throwing header error wp- admin

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is an error:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/webpresenter-Qa/wp-content/plugins/QuoteForm/QuoteForm.php:397)
>   in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/webpresenter-Qa/wp-includes/pluggable.php
>   on line 1196

How can I solve this error?

Comment: i think you have echoed something there... add code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open this file
wp-content/plugins/QuoteForm/QuoteForm.php

and remove space from bottom line or start line of page.

Comment: Thanks Marwal.  Removed the white spaces / worked fine.

Comment: @Gautham welcome :) , please mark select my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like Extra White Space Added in your QuoteForm.php File or You are echoed something before Header

Please Refer Below Link for more details:
https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/php/php-warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent.html